# Menu not showing on varnish enable

Tags: magento-2.1, varnish, topmenu

After Varnish cache enables from Magento admin **catalog menu** disappears

Steps I follows to enable cache

*Admin>>> Store >> Configuration

*Advanced>>>> System
*Full Page Cache

Please find setting screenshot
[image: Settings Varnish]
Please anyone knows the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

please apply following commands..

**php bin/magento upgrade**

**php bin/magento static-content:deploy**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

**chmod -R 777 pub**

Comment: this doesnot works

Comment: please delete generation,tmp,view_preprocessed folder from var. have you got any error in that please check log file

Answer (score 0):

I removed the TTL attribute from `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` and the menu bar was visible again
I don't know whether this solution is appropriate but this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the steps you have listed you did not export the Magento 2.1 Varnish VCL file and set varnish to use it?
You should press the 'Export VCL for Varnish 4' or Varnish 3 depending on what version of varnish you have setup.

I have run into an issue with the frontend menu when my varnish VCL file was not setup correctly.

You can normally find it in the /etc/varnish folder in most linux webserver's.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the TTL attribute (remove ttl="3600") from /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml, and the navigation menu will appear.

For more details regarding this Magento 2 issue, please visit  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3421